# Using hasAuthority when the role is a JSON object

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am having a difficulty in checking the authorities of a user because the role is in a form of a JSON object. I'm not able to access the role. The code is given below

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority({'\"roleId\":\"1\",\"roleName\":\"USER\"'})")
@GET
public List<String> find() {
    return "successfully accessed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible using `hasAuthority` directive.

However, if you are starting new application or have possibility to modify existing role handling, I would recommend to implement your custom role mapper. 
It could look like this:

```
@Bean
public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper myAuthoritiesMapper() {
    return authorities -> {
        return authorities.stream()
            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
            .map(s -> {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                Role role = mapper.readValue(s, Role.class);
                //return roleName or custom string combination of id, name etc.
                return role.getRoleName();
            })
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
            .collect(toList());
    };
}
```

and your Role bean class:

```
class Role {

    private String roleId;
    private String roleName;

    //getters and setters
}
```

After that you could use:

`@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")`

(for example `USER` user roleName)